# How to allow WinDbg to continue till manual breakpoint?

Tags: windbg

I started using WinDbg for some driver debugging. When I am running the target m/c with debugger attached, it is stopping at too many places, then I have to enter g to continue evertime. How can I make WinDbg to stop at only the breakpoints I have placed on my driver code?

I heard there is some command "a" followed by "nop" but cant understand when to use it? Help me Please.

Comment: What are the breakpoints it is hitting?

Comment: I am not sure, may be in something in kernel side..

Answer (score 0):

WinDbg should only be breaking pointing on break points you have set, unless there are `0xCC` bytes in the code.

Try using `bl` to list the break points, and `bc *` to clear them all. Then you can set your breakpoints and go!